# iOS: [imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:] not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

I am attempting to add a UIToolbar to my cameraOverlayView for a custom imagePickerController.  This is the code I want to use:

```
[self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.topToolbar];
```

When trying to add a UIToolbar, nothing shows up.  Encapsulating it into a UIView and setting it to the view property works if I use:

```
[self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.view];
```

But this limits me to using one view for my overlay when I want to add several.  I understand I can encapsulate everything into one big view, however when I do that, my bottom toolbar does not appear properly.

Has anyone had success in adding a UIToolbar as a subview to a cameraOverlayView?

Comment: [self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.topToolbar]; works fine for me. I think we need some more details. How are you initializing your toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need a view to put all the things you need in your cameraOverlay.
for example:

TempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    TempView.alpha = 1.0;

```
anImageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
anImageView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, anImageView1.image.size.width, anImageView1.image.size.height-50);
anImageView1.hidden = NO;
anImageView1.alpha = 1.0f;

tabBarHolder = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
tabBarHolder.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
tabBarHolder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 415, 320, 80);

tampBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 430, 35, 35)];
[tampBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconBack.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tampBtn addTarget:self 
            action:@selector(xup) 
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

ctampBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(145, 430, 35, 35)];
[ctampBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconCamera.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[ctampBtn addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(takephoto) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[TempView addSubview:ctampBtn];
[TempView addSubview:tampBtn];
[TempView addSubview:anImageView1];
[TempView addSubview:tabBarHolder];
[TempView bringSubviewToFront:tabBarHolder];
[TempView bringSubviewToFront: ctampBtn];
[TempView bringSubviewToFront:tampBtn];

imagePicker.cameraOverlayView =TempView;
```

Comment: Right, but say for instance I only want one toolbar.  UIToolbar is a subclass of UIView.  Shouldnt adding a toolbar by itself work?